# Reload contents of multiples DataTable's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

Does someone know or have an idea of how to reload the contents of multiple DataTable's that are inside a page?
This is the code I have until now to initialize the DataTable's:

```
$('.notifications_list_table').dataTable( {          
    "aaSorting": [[ 0,"desc" ]],         
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",           
    "aoColumns": [null,null],            
    "bLengthChange": false        
});
```

As you see, I use a class to identify and initialize all DataTable's. Now I want to update them all when the contents of at least one change on the server.

How could I do it? I saw that fnAjaxReload could be used to load data in one DataTable but here, I want to obtain multiple "aaData" in just one ajax call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, unless you're using long-polling or websockets, the client side can't be aware of the server-side changes. But you can always update at a set interval; for long intervals, the "expense" of the request is trivial. For short intervals (once every second or whatever) it becomes more of a discussion point.

Although the DataTables site has SOME simplified examples, in my opinion it is good practice to store your initialization object to a variable:

```
var notificationTables = $('.notifications_list_table').dataTable( {          
    /* initialization parameters */      
});
```

Now it's just a matter of calling the correct function on the object to update the table. I'm using server-side processing so I re-draw like this:

```
notificationTables.fnDraw(false);
```

What's missing from your sample code is how you're getting the data. The snippet you provided assumes the data is already in the DOM. So the code I've provided above won't actually do anything to get new data.

In my application, I'm doing it this way (and if it's not the best way, I'm thrilled to have someone show me something better! No pride here!):

1. I make an initialization object that contains parameters ALL the tables use.
2. I make a separate new object for each individual table that has the custom values (for example the data source URL, column labels, fnRowCallback functions, etc) and join it to the base object with `jQuery.extend()`, producing a new complete object of all the required parameters.
3. Initialize like this: `var tableOne = $('#tableOne').dataTable(tableOneParams);` (etc; one per table).
4. I simply call the updates separately. My method is a bit more complicated because it has some polling mechanism with pause/resume and idle-detection stuff in it, but it really boils down to a fancied-up version of this:

```
var getNewDT = function() {
  tableOne.fnDraw(false);
  tableTwo.fnDraw(false);
};
```

And then when I need to update them, it would be a simple matter of calling `getNewDT()`.

Hope that sort of helps. ;-)

Comment: Ok, but can't I use just one call to the DataTable's function through a jquery class object? I know I can save the settings in a variable and call DataTable's function for each one of the tables but, if possible, I would like to call it just once ;).

Comment: Ah, by the way, I'm using short polling requests (because of the server). I didn't show how to get the data because I can't find out how to make just one AJAX call and update 3 or more DataTable's based on the JSON results of the AJAX call...

Comment: Trying to populate 3 different tables of data from one JSON data set is going to be a nightmare. Since each table is going to have certain unique parameters anyhow, it's what I consider to be an over-engineered solution to try to do it all in one shot. DataTables exchanges certain parameters back and forth with the server; accessing them in JSON nested one level deeper is going to take at least a bit of work. My advice is to just make 3+ calls, eat the minor HTTP overhead, and be happy. ;-) I have an application making 5 GETs every second or so, and it's barely a blip.

Comment: I found out that I could separate the tables into different "tab's" and then load each one when a user clicks on one of the "tab's". With that solution, I just need to load a set of results for the visible dataTable =). Thanks anyway. This pointed me to the right direction =).

Comment: No problem! Tabs are a great solution if they don't need to see them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used datatables (but looks great). I'm guessing you could do like ...

```
  "sAjaxSource": "yourajax.php?tabid=" + $(this).attr('id')
```

as a parameter, so each table would call the yourajax.php with a different tabid where you can return the table specific data